# Как задать ориентацию экрана landscape при повороте на 180

Tags: android, orientation

Подскажите, как задать landscape ориентацию экрана при повороте экрана на 180 градусов? То есть чтобы при любом из положений телефона landscape был не "вверх ногами"?
Ориентацию я прописал в манифесте

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name=".SliderActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name=".BookLoaderActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name=".BookCardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В значении атрибута `android:screenOrientation` место `landscape` укажите `sensorLandscape`.

[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027992/3069565)